# Vertex paint mode shaded view in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, vertex-colors

When in vertex paint mode - the object being painted is displayed as shadeless.
This makes painting on a complex model difficult - as you cannot really see what you are doing.
You can use dirty vertex paint to make the geometry visible - but this is not ideal.

This is improved in the Blender render textured view using multitexture shading which gives you a shaded view.

In cycles the object remains shadeless in both shaded and textured mode.

Can this be shaded so it is not shadeless when using cycles?

Comment: @Garrett Your screenshot looks shadeless to me (as in there are no dark/light areas dependent on light sources).

Comment: @gandalf3, thanks, I was confused there.  I've deleted my comment.  Also, I have made an edit to OP's question which probably doesn't make sense and I can't figure out how to delete my edit (which has yet to be reviewed)

Comment: @Garrett No worries :). The edit will probably be rejected, but if it isn't it can be rolled back later.

Comment: Since 2.71, you have to select Blender render to have a shadeless model without a wireframe.

Answer (score 2):

This was changed in 2.71, now solid view is displayed with shading, and wireframe view is shadeless:

[image]